# Ionic cordova problem with android and ios build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Node: v10.24.1
Ionic: 5.4.16
Cordova: 9.0.0

I have an ionic application and i want to build the ios/android editions. I follow these steps and i get 0 error messages:

1. ionic cordova resources
2. ionic cordova platform add ios@6.1.1
3. ionic cordova platform add android

But whenever i am trying to test the android app on the emulator of Android Studio i get these messages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq1ok.png)

What can be wrong?

I tried to downgrade,upgrade the versions of (Node, Ionic, Cordova) without any luck.

Comment: Please avoid posting images instead code/logs. Dump the log as `code` inside the questions instead. It will be easier to manage and in general more acceptable by SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when adding new platforms you need to re-build the app. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/cordova/build/

```
ionic cordova build ios
ionic cordova build android
```